# Is it possible to redirect to correct community url if user makes mistake in community url

Tags: community, url

There are two communities in the org: https://myorg.force.com/Invest and https://myorg.force.com/Acquired.

It is working as expected when user is providing correct URL but if user is making any misktake in url like instead of 'Invest' if user gives 'invest', then it throws the message like: https://myorg.force.com/Acquired is under construction.

Is it possible to redirect to correct url if user provides 'invest' instead of 'Invest'. I only need this in scenario when user is giving 'invest'. I know I can't edit underConstruction page as it default salesforce page.

Comment: You can create a new page, write redirection logic basedon URL. Set that page as under construction in sited settings.

Comment: If I am going to Sites option,there are 3 sites,2 for the communities that I have created and other is Myorg sites. Edit option is only available for Myorg sites.How can I set newly created page as under construction?

Comment: See [Assigning Force.com Site Error Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_error_pages.htm&language=th&type=0) in Help

Comment: Rahul, I checked the document but I think Page Not Found Page and Service Not Available Page are used in different scenarios .I was not able to find how to replace page with under construction page.Can you give me some detail on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any site URL was getting redirected to `https://myorg.force.com/Acquired`,I have added site URL redirects in 'Acquired' site rather than in 'Invest'.

Source URL: `/investigators` and Target URL :`https://myorg.force.com/Investigators/login`.

This setting was successfully redirecting to desired page.